Find appears in opposite pane?
Is it possible NPP has a plugin or method of making a plugin easily to force popup windows to appear NOT on-the-code?
Problem:

Desired outcome:


This question is similar to: Notepad++ Can I dock the find window?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
